# Well enough vs. good enough

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

In answer to the question:

> Can you speak English?

Which of the following is correct?

> 1. I can speak it **good enough**.
> 2. I can speak it **well enough**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Standard English, which is what speakers of other languages learn, it's the second.

Comment: Or to rephrase: For people who don't speak English well enough, the first sentence is not good enough.

Comment: @Matt: Such people would do well to avoid saying *"I speak English good"*.